# How do I evaluate a formula in another language?

Tags: vba, language

I'm having some problems with some code and any help would be very appreciated.

I downloaded a code that enables users to have the autocomplete feature in dropdown lists. The code evaluates whether or not the Activecell contains a list and then stores the list as an object. The problem is that my users have the Spanish version of Excel, so the code doesn't work. Particularly, I have problems in this line of the code:

```
Set rFormula = Evaluate(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1)

If rFormula Is Nothing Then 'VBA doesn't recognize the formula so rFormula = Nothing

End 

End If
```

As `ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1 =` the validation formula, but in Spanish. This code works perfectly in my pc because I use the English version.

Comment: Hi Juan, Please edit the question so the code is formated properlly. I use Excel in Spanish and work on VBA Projects with formulas in English never had a problem this way in fact if I send a English formula through VBA it gets translated, never tried the other way around tho. Could you post a sample of what's in `ActiveCell`?

Comment: Take a look at this Tool (Excel Functions Translator): https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-functions-translator-f262d0c0-991c-485b-89b6-32cc8d326889